# Mounting a volume in 'azurerm_linux_web_app' within docker container using Terraform

Tags: azure, docker, terraform, keycloak

I am using an Azure Linux Web App (terraform below) to host a docker container which is the base image of Keycloak, our authentication and authorization provider. We have a requirement to import a theme which can be done by mounting a folder in a specific location within the docker container.

I did see where it is possible to mount blob storage inside of the linux web app, but I'm not sure how to get that mounted inside of the docker container which is defined in the application stack.

### Question

How can I set where the mount point goes rather than /keycloak/custom-themes? I would like it to go under /opt/keycloak/themes?

```
locals {
  storage_account_name = "themestoragean001"
  blob_container_name  = "themes"
  storage_account_kind = "Storage"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "access_service_storage_account" {
  name                     = local.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
  account_kind             = local.storage_account_kind

  tags = merge(
    local.resource_tags,
    {
      Purpose     = "Storage Account for Keycloak themes for ${local.environment}"
      StorageKind = local.storage_account_kind
    }
  )
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "container" {
  name                  = local.blob_container_name
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.access_service_storage_account.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "keycloak_web_app" {
  name                = local.app_service_name
  location            = local.default_region
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.access_service_plan.id
  https_only          = true

  app_settings = {
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL = "https://${local.keycloak_registry_server}"
    PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING   = true
    KC_HOSTNAME                = var.keycloak_hostname
    KC_HTTP_ENABLED            = true
    KC_METRICS_ENABLED         = true
    KC_DB_URL_HOST             = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.keycloak_postgresql_server.fqdn
    KC_DB_URL_PORT             = 5432
    KC_DB_SCHEMA               = "public"
    KC_DB_USERNAME             = local.postgres_admin_username
    KC_DB_PASSWORD             = local.postgres_admin_password
    KEYCLOAK_ADMIN             = local.keycloak_admin_username
    KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD    = local.keycloak_admin_password
    WEBSITES_PORT              = 8080
    KC_PROXY                   = "edge"
    KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT         = false
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  site_config {
    always_on                = true
    http2_enabled            = true
    minimum_tls_version      = 1.2
    app_command_line         = "start --optimized --proxy=edge --hostname-strict-https=false"
    health_check_path        = "/"
    remote_debugging_enabled = false

    application_stack {
      docker_image     = "${local.keycloak_registry_server}/${local.keycloak_image}"
      docker_image_tag = "19.0.3"
    }
  }

  storage_account {
    access_key   = azurerm_storage_account.access_service_storage_account.primary_connection_string
    account_name = local.storage_account_name
    name         = "LinuxThemeMount"
    share_name   = "themes"
    type         = "AzureBlob"
    mount_path   = "/keycloak/custom-themes"
  }

  tags = local.resource_tags
}
```

Azure Linux Web App Configuration:
[image: Azure Linux Web App Configuration]

Comment: Have you defined that in your Dockerfile? I'm guessing that's a default defined somewhere.

Comment: I don't have a custom dockerfile. I'm just pointing to the base image on https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/quarkus/container/Dockerfile that one. I was trying to avoid having a custom dockerfile to manage each time I want to upgrade the base image.

Comment: Is the path defined in that Keycloak image?

Comment: * [Theme documentation in Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes)
* [Theme that I'm trying to override](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/main/themes/src/main/resources/theme/keycloak)
Location in docker container: /opt/keycloak/themes/

Comment: You can see [this docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/p2-inc/keycloak-theme-template/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) where someone is trying to put their theme into a mounted volume. This is my goal within Azure but I do not see how to add the volume within the registry settings.